# File not transferring using python -m http.server from windows 11 to my windows 10 system

Tags: python, http, server

I have made a server in my windows 11 computer using python -m http.server 8080 but when I am trying to access it in my windows 10 computer using the IPv4 address of the windows-11 system and 8080 it is showing This site can't be reached.
I am using the same wifi network to connect both the devices.

To cross check the server  try to access the server in the same system of windows-11 in different browser, it was working.

So, can anyone know how to solve this or actual cause of this problem.